# Tracing the source of an imported subroutine

Tags: perl

I'm modifying a rather large unit test that uses 27 modules before loading the test framework:

```
use Test::Most;
```

When the script reaches this line, it outputs the following warning:

```
mytest.t ........... Subroutine main::explain redefined at mytest.t line 84.
```

Now I can hide the redefine messages by simply undefining the the subroutine before calling use.

```
BEGIN {
    undef *explain;    # Method imported somewhere before.  Hide the redefine messages
}

use Test::Most;
```

However, I'd like to determine which module is importing the other version of explain.

Could use a process of elimination and just comment out everything until I get the warning, but would be nice if there was a more direct route to determining the source.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting `use Devel::Peek qw( ); BEGIN { Devel::Peek::Dump(\&foo); }` before the line that gives the warning will tell you which package (`COMP_STASH`) and file name (`FILE`).

A solution that also gets you the line number is possible. The function's opcode tree could be walked until a `nextstate` is found (which is probably the very first op of the tree). The file name and line number can be extracted from the op. `nextstate` ops set the file and line number issued by runtime warnings.

Notes:

- `#line` directives affect both solutions.
- If a module exports an imported sub, both solution would give the original package and file of origin, not of the intermediary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use perl's introspection facility (called B) for this:

```
use B;
my $gv = B::svref_2object(\&explain)->GV;
printf "%s::%s file %s line %s\n", $gv->STASH->NAME, $gv->NAME, $gv->FILE, $gv->LINE;

Test::Most::explain file /usr/share/perl5/Test/Most.pm line 175
```

(line is the end of the sub, not the beginning)